# A bound on the Fourier coefficients of an $\alpha$-Lipschitz function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am asked to show that if $0 < \alpha < 1$, and if $f \in \Lambda^\alpha(\mathbb{T})$, then we have for $k\neq 0$, $$|\widehat{f}(k)| \leq \pi^\alpha \frac{\|f\|_{\Lambda^1}}{k^\alpha}$$

I applied some properties of inequalities and integrals, but must have gotten a bit carried away because my final bound ended up being far too big as you can see below.

Update:  I am getting closer.  I just don't know where the factor of $k^\alpha$ is coming from.

It has been advised that this theorem might be useful:

> Theorem (Fejér):
>   If $f\in L_p(\mathbb T^d)$, then $\|\sigma_n (f) - f\|_p \to 0$.
>   (Here, $\sigma_n(f) = \frac1{n}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} D_j$).

Attempt #3:

$$
\begin{align*}
|\widehat{f}(k)| &= \left|\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)e^{ikt}\mathrm dt\right|\\
&\leq \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)|\cdot|e^{ikt}|\mathrm dt\\
&= \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)|\mathrm dt\\
&= \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t+\pi) + f(t) - f(t+\pi)|\mathrm dt\\
&\leq \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t + \pi)| + |f(t +\pi) - f(t)|\mathrm dt\\
&= \frac{\pi^\alpha}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{|f(t + \pi)|}{\pi^\alpha} + \frac{|f(t +\pi) - f(t)|}{\pi^\alpha}\mathrm dt\\
&\leq \frac{\pi^\alpha}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t + \pi)| + \frac{|f(t +\pi) - f(t)|}{\pi^\alpha}\mathrm dt\\
&\leq \frac{\pi^\alpha}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \|f\|_{\Lambda^{\alpha}}\mathrm dt\\
&= \pi^\alpha \|f\|_{\Lambda^\alpha}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: for $h>1$, the Lipschitz quotient is less than twice the $L^\infty$ bound.

Comment: This is certainly true but I don't think it helps.  But I think by the mean value theorem any high value of the Lipschitz quotient should also occur for small $h$ values (or as a limit as $h$ becomes small).  This would be helpful because it would allow me to replace $||f||_{\infty}$ with $||f||_{\Lambda^{1}}$ in an inequality chain.

Comment: I'm afraid but what you've done is quite a stretch from your goal. Note that what you want to prove implies that $|\hat{f}(k)| \sim \frac{1}{k^\alpha} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, while with what you've done you only get that it is bounded. I guess that you have Fejér's theorem at hand (I know of no other method) and that you have seen how to do similar estimates for $C^k$-functions, for example, but I wanted to make sure before starting an answer involving facts you don't know.

Comment: We have one theorem available in my notes which is credited to Fejer which I just edited into the question.

As for performing estimates on $C^k$ functions, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I'm sorry in my previous comment I messed up a bit. The argument I had in mind was uniform convergence of the Fejér sums to $f$ for $f \in \Lambda_{\alpha}$ and for that one needs a much stronger result than the simple (but neat) trick given by Andrew.

Comment: Attempt #3 does not show any decay. Each derivative of smoothness of a function usually translates to a power of $\xi$ decay in the fourier transform (and vice versa). You are trying to show that this works for the fractional Lipschitz smoothness as well.

Comment: @Kyle: I have added a small bit of motivation at the end of my answer to show how smoothness is used to get decay in the fourier transform.

Comment: Since $k$ can be positive or negative, the problem should read $$|\widehat{f}(k)|\leq\pi^\alpha\frac{\|f\|_{\Lambda^\alpha}}{|k|^\alpha}$$ Also, you probably want $\Lambda^\alpha$ in your norm instead of $\Lambda^1$.

Comment: Kyle, I notice that you have posted a number of questions regarding Fourier analysis on the torus and Lipschitz functions. I suggest that you look at chapter 3 of *Classical Fourier Analysis* by Loukas Grafakos (especially section 3.2.) where these topics are discussed in great detail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For integer $k\ne0$
$$
c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(t)e^{-ikt}dt=
-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(t)e^{ik(t-\pi/k)}dt=
-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f\left(t+\frac\pi k\right)e^{ikt}dt.
$$
Taking one half of the sum of these expressions for $c_k$ we have
$$
|c_k|=\frac{1}{4\pi}\left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(f(t)-f\left(t+\frac\pi k\right)\right)e^{-ikt}dt\right|\leq\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|f(t)-f\left(t+\frac\pi k\right)\right|dt\leq
$$
$$
\frac{||f||_{\Lambda^{\alpha}}}{4\pi}\int_0^{2 \pi } \left|\frac{\pi }{k}\right|^{\alpha } \, dt= \frac{\pi^\alpha}{2|k|^\alpha}||f||_{\Lambda^{\alpha}}.
$$

Comment: Wow.  I would never have thought to do that.  Is this a common technique?  I'm trying to see what should have suggested this.  I suppose that the $(\frac{\pi}{k})^{\alpha}$ should have tipped me off that I would need to somehow obtain $|f(x) - f(y)|$ in my expression, where $|x - y| = \frac{\pi}{k}$.  I will be honest in my homework and make it clear that someone showed me this trick.

Thank you.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, it's a common technique in the theory of trigonometric series for estimating moduli of continuity. See, for example, in Zygmund, Trigonometric Series, vol.1, ch.2, $\S4$, http://ebookee.org/Trigonometric-Series-Vol-1_212310.html

Answer (score 7):

As I mentioned in my comment, we want to use the smoothness of $f$ to get a decay in $\hat{f}$. To make use of the smoothness of  $f$ (which is given as a bound on $\Delta_s f$), consider the Fourier Transform of $\Delta_s f(t)=f(t+s)-f(t)$:
$$
\hat{f}(k)(e^{2\pi iks}-1)=\int_{\mathbb{T}}(f(t+s)-f(t))\;e^{-2\pi ikt}\;\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
\begin{align}
|\hat{f}(k)||e^{2\pi iks}-1|
&\le\int_{\mathbb{T}}|f(t+s)-f(t)|\;\mathrm{d}t\\
&\le |s|^\alpha\|f\|_{\Lambda(\alpha)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Since $|e^{2\pi iks}-1|=|2\sin(\pi ks)|\ge|4ks|$ for $|ks|\le\frac{1}{2}$, we get
$$
|\hat{f}(k)|\le \frac{|s|^{\alpha-1}}{|4k|}\|f\|_{\Lambda(\alpha)}\tag{3}
$$
If we choose $s=\frac{1}{2k}$ (so that $|ks|\le\frac{1}{2}$), $(3)$ becomes
$$
|\hat{f}(k)|\le \frac{1}{2^{\alpha+1}|k|^\alpha}\|f\|_{\Lambda(\alpha)}\tag{4}
$$
I think the difference in constant is due to our use of different normalizations of the Fourier Transform. Since this is homework, I will let you convert.

---

**More Motivation:** In a comment, I mentioned that one dervative of smoothness in $f$ yields one power of $k$ in the decay of $\hat{f}$. This is usually accomplished using integration by parts to show that
$$
\int_\mathbb{T}f^{\;\prime}(t)\;e^{-2\pi ikt}\;\mathrm{d}t=2\pi ik\int_\mathbb{T}f(t)\;e^{-2\pi ikt}\;\mathrm{d}t\tag{5}
$$
Unfortunately, we can't take derivatives, but as we see above
$$
\int_\mathbb{T}\Delta_sf(t)\;e^{-2\pi ikt}\;\mathrm{d}t=(e^{2\pi iks}-1)\int_\mathbb{T}f(t)\;e^{-2\pi ikt}\;\mathrm{d}t\tag{6}
$$
which can be used the same way.

Comment: I confess I don't follow what you are doing in the first half of your answer.  I wouldn't worry too much though, as the question has been answered already.  As for the second part, yes we definitely proved this in class.

Comment: @Kyle: From the sound of your comments to Andrew, you are still somewhat uncertain about what is going on. I would like to help make you more certain. Equation $(1)$ is simply equation $(6)$. That transfers the smoothness of $f$ to the decay of $\hat{f}$. Equation $(2)$ simply quantifies the Lipschitz condition. As you mentioned, we are interested in the Lipschitz condition for small shifts, and $|e^{2\pi iks}-1|\sim 2\pi ks$ for small $ks$. Therefore, we divide the left of $(2)$ by $|e^{2\pi iks}-1|$ and the right by $4ks$ to get $(3)$.

Comment: @Kyle: Equation $(3)$ is true for any $s\le\frac{1}{2k}$, but the smaller we make $s$, the worse the estimate is ($\alpha-1<0$), so we choose as large an $s$ as we can, i.e. $\frac{1}{2k}$.  That gives us $(4)$.

Comment: To be totally honest, I do understand the steps in Andrew's answer.  I just don't understand the approach behind choosing them yet.  I will have to spend some time thinking about it still.  I may have to read your explanation more carefully before I follow the steps precisely.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ robjohn: I dont know why I didn't understand this earlier.  I just read it now and it is very clear.  Thanks for this alternative approach.

(Spending Thanksgiving weekend with family is clearly a good brain refresher. :)  Hope yours is going well.  Cheers!)

Comment: @Kyle: Thanksgiving is next month for us here in the colonies :-) Sounds like yours was good.